# Correct way to use relay mounting tabs

Tags: relay, mount

I am working with relays similar to this:
[image]

The mounting tabs along the bottom surface (circled red in the photo) have what look to be scoring marks. The one I have in front of me has several more of these on the underside as well. Each mark is present on the top & bottom surfaces.

**Is it correct to break off the tabs at the scoring lines that aren't being used / are in the way?**

Or are those metal indentations for some other purpose?

---

Edit: Just some more detail - these are HVAC fan relays. I'm using them for exactly that purpose but not as a replacement part; there is no existing mounting location to compare against.

Comment: Link to datasheet, please. Put it in the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: @Transistor I'm looking but no luck in finding one yet. These seem to be "generic" parts from various makers but none yet has that info... I'll update if I can find it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

These are 'Lucar' / 'Faston' tabs, almost certainly 250 series (1/4" wide). These are meant to be used with matching push-on connectors on the ends of flying leads. They are not meant to be plugged into a socket. The relay is meant to be chassis mounted by the mounting tabs.

As for whether the score marks on the mounting tabs can be used to help you break them off, try it. The worst you can do is rip the tab out of the bottom and trash the relay.

Answer (score 0):

Sans datasheet this is just a guess but I would think that you are correct and this is an attempt to manufacture a more universal replacement relay that can replace several common HVAC relays in one.

I'm not sure how successful they have been- if the relay doesn't fit I would be tempted to use my Wiss® metal snips to cut it off rather than bending it back and forth to fatigue it to death.

The score marks at the bends, on the other hand, may simply be an attempt to get the bend as sharp as possible.

Answer (score -1):

No, these tabs are not meant to be broken off.  It looks like this relay is intended to be plugged into a socket.  Check the datasheet or the manufacturer web site to find the mating socket.

The reason some relays are intended for sockets is because relays wear out in demanding applications.  By using a socket, you can design for the inevitable maintenance that must be performed regularly.